# Include a filtered set of records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4.1, lazy-loading

Is this possible?

```
var results = (from c in _context.properties
               where c.strap == somevalue
               select c).include("characteristics).where(characteristics.cat_cd != 'DD');
```

essentially I want to create this query.  I will be include(ing) other tables as the app grows.

```
select * from properties p,characteristics c
where 
p.strap = c.strap
and c.cat_cd <> 'DD'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I learned.

```
var results = (from c in _context.properties
               where c.Characteristics.Any(c=>c.cat_cd == "DD") select c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply make a `join` statement:

```
var set = from property in _context.Properties
          join characteristic in _context.Characteristcs on property.strap equals characteristic.strap
          select new 
          {
              Property = property,
              Characteristic = characteristic
          }
```

Comment: But you are declaring the `on` clause. I would like to avoid that and have EF handle the relationship and I would apply the filter.